# Logstash Oracle JDBC (Failed to load ojdbc8.jar)

Tags: oracle, elasticsearch, kibana, ojdbc, logstash-jdbc

I configure logstash connection for oracle but not working.

Error: failed to load c:\ojdbc8.jar

Do you have any solution for this situation?

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.10.10:1521/TESTDB"
    jdbc_user => "SCOTT"
    jdbc_password => "TIGER"
    #jdbc_validate_connection => true
    jdbc_driver_library => "C:\ojdbc8.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM SALES_DATA_SAMPLE"

 }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    index => "salesdata"
    document_type => "salesdata"
    document_id => "%{uid}"
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the `ojdbc8.jar` located at the root of your `C:\`?

Comment: Yes I have. this is right path and file location "C:\ojdbc8.jar" But not load.

Comment: Try with `C:/ojdbc8.jar`, the backslash might be an escape character. I found someone doing something similar here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-mysql-using-jdbc-on-windows-library-error/37313

Comment: Failed to load C:/ojdbc8.jar {:exception=>#<TypeError: failed to coerce jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader to java.net.URLClassLoader>}

Comment: Your Logstash configuration looks fine to me. <br>
I have a configured logstash pipeline with an ojdbc6.jar driver and logstash6.5.3 working fine with configurations very similar to yours. <br>
Maybe you are having some compatibility issues. I found a similar issue [reported in github](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-jdbc/issues/331).

Comment: Try giving the path as c:\\ojdbc8.jar and that should work

Comment: This is because it isn't Java 11 compatible, see https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-jdbc/issues/331

Answer (score 8):

It's just a work around. Just copy the driver Jar file to **/logstash-core/lib/jars/** directory.

Comment: It was a great work around. Helps me quiet a lot. Thank you @Shrikant